# Ethereum protocol - description fields on Alethio block explorer

Tags: explorers, ibft

I am using Alethio block explorer in an IBFT2 based chain. I am trying to understand some fields there.

Does anyone know what they mean?

- Are the COMMITSEALS the signature of the validators?
- What is MIX HASH?
- What is LOGS BLOOM? Are the logs of the blocks? Is it a kind of processing using a bloom filter?
- I also do not understand what SHA3UNCLES. It also appears on EtherScan with the following description: "The mechanism which Ethereum Javascript RLP encodes an empty string". I know RLP but I still could not understand why this info is relevant to be presented in a block explorer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/Concepts/Consensus/IBFT/) is a description to some of the changes to the Ethereum's block header for IBFT. In particular:

- **mixHash**: Fixed magic number `0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365` for Istanbul block identification.
- **ommersHash** (SHA3_UNCLES): Must be UNCLE_HASH as uncles are meaningless outside of PoW. UNCLE_HASH is a constant defined as `Keccak256(RLP([]))` as uncles are meaningless outside of PoW.
- **CommittedSeal**: The list of commitment signature seals as consensus proof.

LogsBloom isn't mentioned so it should have the same purpose than in Ethereum. It is a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) constructed from the events to facilitate search.